# Excluding namespaces from XML

Tags: xslt, transform, transformation

My xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:go="http://www.google.com"
    exclude-result-prefixes="go">
<xsl:include href="SomeLibrary.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:call-template name="SomeTemplate">
            <xsl:with-param name="Element" select="'randomParam'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The SomeLibrary.xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.google.com">
    <xsl:template name="SomeTemplate">
    <xsl:param name="Element"/>
        <Blabla>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Element" />    
        </Blabla>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input xml: just use an empty XML. The result is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Blabla xmlns="http://www.google.com">
    randomParam
</Blabla>
```

What I want is to have the "Blabla" node without a namespace. How can I remove it or make sure it doesn't get there, without modifying my "SomeLibrary.xsl"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In case you don't want to edit the imported stylesheet code, the way to remove the namespace is with a two-pass transformation (which in XSLT 1.0 requires using an `xxx:node-set()` extension function):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext" >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
     <xsl:call-template name="SomeTemplate">
                <xsl:with-param name="Element" select="'randomParam'"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:variable name="vPass1" select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$vrtfPass1/node()" mode="pass2"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*" mode="pass2">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass2"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="SomeTemplate" xmlns="http://www.google.com">
   <xsl:param name="Element"/>
            <Blabla>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Element" />
            </Blabla>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted result (the default namespace removed) is produced**:

```
<Blabla>randomParam</Blabla>
```

**Update**:

The OP has indicated in a comment that he is using Xalan 2.07.

Below is almost the same solution, but with namespace and name for the `xxx:node-set()` function, as used in Xalan:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" exclude-result-prefixes="x" >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
     <xsl:call-template name="SomeTemplate">
                <xsl:with-param name="Element" select="'randomParam'"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:variable name="vPass1" select="x:nodeset($vrtfPass1)"/>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$vrtfPass1/node()" mode="pass2"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*" mode="pass2">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass2"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="SomeTemplate" xmlns="http://www.google.com">
   <xsl:param name="Element"/>
            <Blabla>
                <xsl:value-of select="$Element" />
            </Blabla>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't work ("compile" errors). Thank you for the effort though. I'll revisit this some time in the future.

Comment: @Buffalo: I always test my code before publishing it -- if you just apply this transformation (strictly copy and paste, no modifications) to the provided source XML document (strictly copy and paste, no modifications) -- then the result must be the one in this answer. If something doesn't "compile" this means that you have modified the transformation or the XML document, or both.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev nice two-pass solution; I will store this one for future reference!

Comment: @Buffalo: The only possible issue is if your XSLT 1.0 processor doesn't implement EXSLT `node-set()` -- in this case you need to use the `xxx:node-set()` extension function that your particular XSLT 1.0 processor implements. What XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: @Buffalo: then replace in my code `ext:node-set` with `nodeset`. Xalan implements this extrnsion function under the name `x:nodeset`. Also, change the namespace `xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common` to `xmlns:x="xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"` . See this link for an example: http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensionslib.html#nodeset

Comment: @Buffalo: I updated my answer with code that should execute with Xalan.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly create them with:

```
<xsl:element name="Blabla" namespace="">...</xsl:element>
```

but this means fiddling with the `SomeLibrary.xsl` file.

Answer (score 0):

add `exclude-result-prefixes="go"` to the stylesheet element.
and, of course, update the namespace declaration from the default one to `xmlns:go="http://www.google.com"`

Comment: in SomeLibrary.xsl but I now notice that you don't wish to edit that. I wonder too then, whether there is another way to do this...